ModuleNotFoundError with airflow db init
So I'm attempting to do an A/B deployment of airflow on EKS (self-managed) and I've run into the problem of needing extra databases for my environments. (if this can be avoided, I'd love to know how, but that's not my question).
I've created a Postgres database in my cluster called stage1 that the airflow_user has access to. I do not have airflow deployed to that EKS environment yet. I set AIRFLOW__CORE__SQL_ALCHEMY_CONN correctly and airflow db check works fine. When I run airflow db init I get the below error:
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'airflow.www.fab_security'
One big constraint is that we are on airflow==2.1.2 and python==3.6 and I will try to upgrade to more recent versions after the migration.
Here is my process to replicate:
conda create -n airflow_212 python-==3.6
pip install apache-airflow==2.1.2 --constraint="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/apache/airflow/constraints-2.1.2/constraints-3.6.txt" --no-cache-dir
pip install psycopg2-binary --no-cache-dir
export AIRFLOW__CORE__SQL_ALCHEMY_CONN=postgresql+psycopg2://username:password@host:port/dbname
airflow db check
airflow db init

Update: I decided to skip stage and it works fine in prod! However I get this issue when running:  airflow users add-role -u rriley -r Admin . So it is still a blocker.

The fab_security module is part of Flask-AppBuilder (FAB), which is a dependency of Airflow. It's possible that the version of Flask-AppBuilder required by Airflow is not properly installed. You can manually install the required version of Flask-AppBuilder pip install flask-appbuilder==3.3.0

Ok, this is something I haven't seen before. But that did not resolve the issue. I also found a dependency issue with gunicorn==19.4.0 and updated it to 19.5.0
